# using TableSorter to sort using epoch time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, tablesorter

I have java based web app. In the front end i am receiving a set of objects. One of the fields in the object is date.

Now I am trying to sort by date using  . but I am not seeing the sorted result.

```
  function update() {

var rows = $('#results tr:gt(0)'); 
 rows.each(function(index) {    
 //code to show or hide rows based on some logic
 }

 $('#results').tablesorter({
            sortList:[[8,0]]
        });

}
```

In my  9th field is epoch time. so i am trying to sort  based on that column.This column is hidden

But I am not seeing the effect.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the update function is supposed to resort the table after rows have been shown/hidden. If you want to resort the table, don't reinitialize the plugin, just trigger the `sorton` method:

```
$("#results").trigger("sorton", [ [[8,0]] ]);
```

Note that there are an extra set of brackets around the sortList value, this is because the trigger method needs the parameters to be passed via an array ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)). Also check out [this example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html).

Comment: Hi Mottie, Thanks for reply. I tried it but no change. I didnt initialize it anywhere . Can i directly trigger without initializing

Comment: Yeah, but only once. If you plan on calling that update function a second time, it'll ignore the sort.